# How can I get the values of XML nodes depending on the content of another node by using XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

That's my very first question according to XSLT. I would like to transform a XML structure by using XSLT.

**The relevant part of my XML source**:

```
<field tag="ElementName">
  <subfield code="S">p</subfield>
  <subfield code="a">Content 1 for S=P</subfield>
</field>
<field tag="ElementName">
  <subfield code="S">p</subfield>
  <subfield code="a">Content 2 for S=P</subfield>
</field>
<field tag="ElementName">
  <subfield code="S">p</subfield>
  <subfield code="a">Content 3 for S=P</subfield>
</field>
<field tag="ElementName">
  <subfield code="S">g</subfield>
  <subfield code="a">Content 1 for S=G</subfield>
</field>
<field tag="ElementName">
  <subfield code="S">g</subfield>
  <subfield code="a">Content 2 for S=G</subfield>
</field>
<field tag="ElementName">
  <subfield code="S">s</subfield>
  <subfield code="a">Content 1 for S=S</subfield>
</field>
<field tag="ElementName">
  <subfield code="S">s</subfield>
  <subfield code="a">Content 2 for S=S</subfield>
</field>
<field tag="ElementName">
  <subfield code="S">s</subfield>
  <subfield code="a">Content 3 for S=S</subfield>
</field>
<field tag="ElementName">
  <subfield code="S">s</subfield>
  <subfield code="a">Content 4 for S=S</subfield>
</field>
```

Next what I would like the **XML to look like after transformation**:

```
<field tag="ElementName_P">
  <subfield code="a">Content 1 for S=P</subfield>
  <subfield code="a">Content 2 for S=P</subfield>
  <subfield code="a">Content 3 for S=P</subfield>
</field>
<field tag="ElementName_G">
  <subfield code="a">Content 1 for S=G</subfield>
  <subfield code="a">Content 2 for S=G</subfield>
</field>
<field tag="ElementName_S">
  <subfield code="a">Content 1 for S=S</subfield>
  <subfield code="a">Content 2 for S=S</subfield>
  <subfield code="a">Content 3 for S=S</subfield>
  <subfield code="a">Content 4 for S=S</subfield>
</field>
```

I know how to get the attribute values and the field values using xsl:variable and xsl:value-of. What I would like to know is how to group the contents from the subfields with code="a". Have been trying for hours. Are there any possibilities using XPath?

Thx for support!

Comment: This is a *grouping* question. Do a search - it's one of the most frequently asked questions here. Note that answers are different for XSLT 1.0 or 2.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As example how this can be done in XSLT 1.0:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output indent="yes" encoding="utf-8" method="xml" 
            omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:key name="sCode" match="subfield[@code='S']" use="." />
  <xsl:variable name="smallcase" select="'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'" />
  <xsl:variable name="uppercase" select="'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'" />

  <xsl:template match="field">
    <xsl:for-each select="subfield[generate-id() =
                          generate-id(key('sCode', .)[1])]">
      <xsl:variable name="elements" select="key('sCode', .)" />
      <field>
        <xsl:attribute name="tag" select="concat('ElementName_', 
                                  translate($elements, $smallcase, $uppercase))"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//subfield[(./text() =  $elements)]"
                             mode="sorted"/>  
      </field>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="subfield" mode="sorted">
     <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:attribute name="code" select="."/>
        <xsl:value-of select="./following-sibling::subfield[@code='a']"/>
     </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

when applied to your input XML has the ouput

```
<field tag="ElementName_P">
  <subfield code="p">Content 1 for S=P</subfield>
  <subfield code="p">Content 2 for S=P</subfield>
  <subfield code="p">Content 3 for S=P</subfield>
</field>
<field tag="ElementName_G">
  <subfield code="g">Content 1 for S=G</subfield>
  <subfield code="g">Content 2 for S=G</subfield>
</field>
<field tag="ElementName_S">
  <subfield code="s">Content 1 for S=S</subfield>
  <subfield code="s">Content 2 for S=S</subfield>
  <subfield code="s">Content 3 for S=S</subfield>
  <subfield code="s">Content 4 for S=S</subfield>
</field>
```

In case you're using XSLT 2.0 it wouldn't be necessary to translate the code value for the `ElementName` tag in the output but you could just use the function `uppercase()`.

As references for XSLT grouping you can have a look at e.g. http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.xml and http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/N4486.html